# Rocky beach accessible from Faro by public transport

Tags: public-transport, beaches, portugal

We'll be spending a couple days this summer in Faro, and we would like to visit a nice beach with cliffs near the sea.

The difficulty is that we won't have a car, so we will use public transport, but it's hard to get clear information about the network there (I found [algarvebus](http://www.algarvebus.info/), but it's still a lot to process), and trains run far from the coast.

I found that [Praia da Marinha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praia_da_Marinha) is regarded as the most beautiful one, but that is very far away. I was trying to find others that are easier to access, without much success ([Falésia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fal%C3%A9sia_Beach) is closer, but not with buses).

**Is there any similar beach on the coast which is accessible by train/bus** plus a short walk (let's say 2-3 km at most)?

Comment: Would Praia de Faro work? It's not got the big cliffs but is accessible by public transport